# App Engine webapp.RequestHandler child instances has no self.request during __init__

Tags: google-app-engine, request-headers

i use modified webapp.RequestHandler for handling requests in my app:

```
class MyRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    """
    Request handler with some facilities like user.
    self.out is the dictionary to pass to templates 
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.out = {
            'user': users.get_current_user(),
            'logout_url': users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            }

    def render(self, template_name):
        """
        Shortcut to render templates
        """
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_name, self.out))


class DeviceList(MyRequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.out['devices'] = GPSDevice.all().fetch(1000)
        self.render('templates/device_list.html')
```

but I get an exception:

```
line 28, in __init__
    self.out['logout_url'] = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
AttributeError: 'DeviceList' object has no attribute 'request'
```

When the code causing exception is moved out of `__init__` everything's fine:

```
class MyRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    """
    Request handler with some facilities like user.
    self.out is the dictionary to pass to templates and initially it contains user object for example
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.out = { 'user': users.get_current_user(), }

    def render(self, template_name):
        """
        Shortcut to render templates
        """
        self.out['logout_url'] = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_name, self.out))
```

Whi is that? Why there's no `self.request` after parent's (i.e. webapp.RequestHandler's) `__init__` was executed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requesthandlerclass.html#RequestHandler_initialize

> initialize(request, response)
>   Initializes the handler instance with
>   Request and Response objects.
>   Typically, the WSGIApplication does
>   this after instantiating the handler
>   class.

Looks like you want to override initialize instead of init if you're expecting the request object to already be populated.

Comment: Thanks :-) (I was looking into docs but apparently not too deep)